# Adjust and fix appearance of lightning-map LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, iframe, lightning-base-component, shadow-dom

In my Lightning Web Component, I am using the `<lightning-map>` Base Component to display a Google map.

I have a few display issues and things I would like to adjust, but It doesn’t work as expected.

[image]

1. Hide remove all button elements (Street View, +-, Modes)
2. Smaller map markers

I tried a global CSS from a static resource:

```
/* Hide button */
.gm-svpc, .gmnoprint {
    display: none !important;
}
```

loaded like this but it has no effect

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from "lwc";

import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import mapCssFixes from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/mapCssFixes'

export default class XYZ extends LightningElement {

    // Note: Load custom style to fix map issues(Workaround by Don Robbins)
    renderedCallback() {
        loadStyle(this, mapCssFixes)
            .then(response => {
                    console.log('custom styles loaded');
                }
            );
    }
```

I guess that is because of `Shadow-DOM` and `iframe`.

**Any workarounds, tricks I could try until Salesforce improves this component?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is finally getting improved in [Spring 21 release](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_map_enhance.htm&type=5&release=230).

You can remove the not needed buttons with the new property mapOptions

```
mapOptions = {
      'disableDefaultUI': true // when true disables Map|Satellite, +|- zoom buttons
      'draggable': false, // when false prevents panning by dragging on the map
    };
```

---

```
<template>
  <lightning-map
    map-markers={mapMarkers}
    options={mapOptions}
    >
   </lightning-map>
 </template>
```

Also, the icons can use an SVG icon other than the standard icon using `mapIcon`

```
mapMarkers = [
    {   
        location: {
            City: 'San Francisco',
            Country: 'USA',
            PostalCode: '94105',
            State: 'CA',
            Street: '425 Mission St', 
        },
        mapIcon : {
            path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
            fillColor: '#CF3476',
            fillOpacity: .5,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            scale: .10,
        }
   }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do from a Stylesheet perspective because the map is embedded in an iframe. Style defined in a parent window can't affect a child document in an iframe. That holds true since the beginning of HTML, it's not LWC related.

If you'd like to cutomize a map component, you'll have to create your own.
If you want to do down that path, I would recommend [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/). It works great, it's easier to setup than Google Maps and it's quite powerful. We used it for several demos but nothing I can share unfortunately.

However, it turns out that someone just shared a [Leaflet LWC sample](https://github.com/jlyon87/lwc-leaflet-map). I haven't tested but it looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try loading the style sheet in connectedCallback.

```
connectedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this, mapCssFixes)
      ]).then(() => {
        console.log(' css loaded');  
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error received in handling css'+error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation for loadStyle: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_third_party_library

Comment: Style can't affect the map because it's in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

> Smaller map markers

From the documentation: "Custom marker icons are currently not supported"
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation